# Sum of two elements is $x$

Tags: algorithms

I read the following problem in the book Introduction to Algorithms by Cormen, Leiserson, Rives, Stein and I couldn't make any progress with it.

There is a set of $n$ numbers. Give an algorithm that decides in $O(n\times\log \space n)$ steps if there are two numbers in the set whose sum is a given number ($x$). Could you also tell me if it can be generalized (are there $k$ elements in the set whose sum is $x$)?

Comment: What does the complexity $O(n\log n)$ hint at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by thinking how you would identify such a pair.

The most obvious way is to pick the first number and try adding it to every other number. If this fails, move on to the second number and try adding it to every other number (except the first). This method will test every possible pairing and is therefore $O(n^2)$.

So you now have to find a way to improve your algorithm.

Hint: Could you do something to the list of numbers first to give yourself a better chance of discovering a pair that add to $x$?